# I want to send data to from a Javascript app to a Flora board to display a color on the LED through Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a JavaScript application to send a number to a Flora board via Bluetooth, depending on the range of the number, the LED displays a certain color. The application is able to connect to the board but it isn't able to light up the LED. The number is saved in a session storage from a previous page.

Initial variables are:

```
var app = {}; // Object holding the functions and variables
var BluefruitUART = null; // Object holding the BLE device
var BLEDevice = {}; // Object holding Bluefruit BLE device information
BLEDevice.name = 'Adafruit Bluefruit LE'; // Bluefruit name
BLEDevice.services = ['6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e']; // Bluefruit services UUID
BLEDevice.writeCharacteristicUUID = '6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e'; // Bluefruit writeCharacteristic UUID
```

Then the function that sends the message to the Arduino is:

```
app.sendMessage = function(message, int index) // Send a message to Bluefruit device
{
   var data = evothings.ble.toUtf8(message);
   BluefruitUART.writeCharacteristic(
        BLEDevice.writeCharacteristicUUID,
        data,
        function() {
          console.log('Sent: ' + message);
        },
        function(errorString) {
          console.log('BLE writeCharacteristic error: ' + errorString);
        }
    )
};
```

The button that sends the message to the Arduino is:

```
<button class="green wide big" onclick="app.sendMessage('on', sessionStorage.AQI)">ON</button>
```

The code on the Arduino IDE is:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  setupBluefruit();
}

void loop() {
  String message = "";
  while (ble.available()) {
    int c = ble.read();
    Serial.print((char)c);
    message.concat((char)c);
    if (message == "on, int") {
      message = "";
      Serial.println("\nTurning LED ON");
      digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);
    }
    else if (message == "off") {
      message = "";
      Serial.println("\nTurning LED OFF");
     digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);
    }
    else if (message.length() > 3) {
      message = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
if (message == "on, int") {
```

Is comparing the message string with the literal `"on, int"`. However in your actual messages you are going to sent some actual numbers, not the string `"int"`. To check if `message` begins with `"on"`, you can use the [startsWith](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringStartsWith) function, like this:

```
if (message.startsWith("on")) {
```

With a bit of luck this will get the LED turning on.

The next thing is to actually pass some numbers. In your `sendMessage` function you never actually use the `index` parameter, so you need to change it to do so. Then inside the Arduino code you can parse the number from your string, something like this:

```
if (message.startsWith("on")) {
    int index = message.substring(3).toInt();
```

which will chop off the first 3 characters of the string (the `"on "`) and convert the remainder to an int. Then you can use it to set the LED color. For more information on Arduino string processing functions, see [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject).